# destroy non-Qwidget member variable in custom QWidget

Tags: qt

For a custom `QWidget` class that contains both `QWidget` member variable and non-widget member variable, what is the proper way to write the destructor of the class? For example, I have

```
class CustomWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QWidget* x_widget; 
        SomeOtherClass* x_non_widget;
}
```

and set the parent of `x_widget` to `this` when creating it, how should I write the destructor? Should I just put `delete x_non_widget` in the destructor?

Comment: The base class destructor will handle deleting child objects. You just need to handle deleting the non-children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidget` inherits from `QObject`, so if its parent is set, then the object gets deleted **automatically** when the parent is being destroyed. Since you set `this` as parent, then the child `x_widget` gets automatically deleted when the parent `CustomWidget` instance is deleted. So no destructor is needed in this case.

Note however that if you put a widget into a layout, then it is re-parented (if it already had a parent) to the widget which holds the layout. But I guess this is not your case.

If your non-widget object **is derived** from `QObject` then you can set its parent too. And then you do not need to delete it in destructor because it will be deleted automatically the same way as widgets.

If your non-widget is **not derived** from `QObject` or you do not want to set a parent for it (for any reason, e.g. you move it to a thread), then you can wrap it in some owning/strong smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or `QScopedPointer`. Then it will be deleted automatically via the smart pointer. You do not need to delete it in the destructor either.

And only if you do not want to wrap it in any such an owning/strong smartpointer, you need to delete it in the destructor manually.

PS: Aside from the question you have, for non-owned members kept by pointer inherited from `QObject` you can also benefit from using `QPointer`, which is an extremely handy class which ensures automatic nullification of the pointer when the object gets deleted anywhere in the code. So no more invalid pointers to deleted `QObject`s... But unlike owning/strong smart pointers, `QPointer` does not ensure automatic object deletion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers nearly all my questions on Qt memory management! If I have a parent widget and a child widget, and I call `delete child_widget` somewhere in the code, will that crash the program later when the parent is deleted which calls `delete child_widget` again even though it is already deleted?

Comment: No, it will not crash. The reason is that when you delete the child manually, the child is removed from the parent's list of children and then it is not deleted again. Unless you try to delete it manually (e.g. by some mistake in destructor) again, of course. Therefore if you keep a pointer to such an object which you want to delete manually earlier than the parent, it is benefitial to keep it via `QPointer` because then the pointer is nullified automatically and you do not have a dangling pointer to a deleted object.